# JavaScript .join() doesn't get rid of commas in a looped multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, multidimensional-array, push

I'm relatively new to JavaScript and coding, and I've been trying to push strings into an empty miltidimensional array via two for-loops, and convert the output array into a string. My idea is that the string gets added to the array, until the row- and columnlength are met. The push() works fine, but somehow join.('') does not get rid of the commas in the inner arrays. Here's my code (I'm building a project in codecademy, and the output is in bash):

```
var rowlength = 3;
var collength = 3;

function attempt() {
  let randomarray = [];
  let i;
  let j;
  for(j = 0; j < rowlength; j++) {
    randomarray.push([]);
    for(i = 0; i < collength; i++) {
      randomarray[j].push('x');
    }
  }
    return randomarray.join('' + '\n');
};

console.log(attempt());
```

Output:

```
x,x,x
x,x,x
x,x,x
```

The output I want:

```
xxx
xxx
xxx
```

Can somebody explain to me what I'm doing wrong? I've tried moving the join('') elsewhere but the output remains the same, and google gives me nothing so far...

Comment: You need to join the inner array as well.

Comment: Although no real reason for it to be an array to start with, you could just do `randomarray.push("");` and then `randomarray[j] += "x";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not joining the inner array, once you have done that then in the end you can join the way you are already doing. Make a temporary array in the the first loop and then push the joined array to your main `randomarray`. Now you will have an array with correct row content.

Update you `attempt` function like this:

```js
function attempt() {
  let randomarray = [];
  let i;
  let j;
  for(let j = 0; j < rowlength; j++) {
    let innerArray = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < collength; i++) {
      innerArray.push('x');
    }
    randomarray.push(innerArray.join(''))
  }
    return randomarray.join('' + '\n');
};
```

Comment: Oh, I see, I suspected I didn't join the inner array, but I couldn't figure out where to put the second join... it kept throwing errors. But this helps, thanks a lot!